# C# get name of object pair

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

```
var myObject =  new { Id = 0, Name = "Test" };
```

I would like to get key name into variable in other part of project for ex.:

```
var keyName = someObject[0];  //someObject is passed myObject;
var value = someObject[1];
//Output keyName = Id; value = 0;
```

I know that dictionary would be good, but I have to stick to the delaration of myObject;

Comment: Why do you need to access them based on index, you can access its properties like `myObject.Id`, `myObject.Name` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the properties of your object this way:

```
myObject.GetType().GetProperties()
```

and the names e.g.

```
myObject.GetType().GetProperties()[0].Name //("Id")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with reflection, because variables won't have a name once compiled to IL. However, you can use expression trees and promote the variable to a closure:

```
static string GetVariableName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;

    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

You can use this method as follows:

```
static void Main()
{
    var someVar = 3;

    Console.Write(GetVariableName(() => someVar));
}
```

Note that this is pretty slow, so don't use it in performance critical paths of your application.

For a more complete example, see [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=37).